# Gigya button doesn't work

Tags: facebook, twitter, gigya

I have Gigya implemented in my site.

It works as I would expect except for the first button doesn't fire off when clicking on it.

In my share bar I have LinkedIN, twitter, google and facebook. But, linkedIn doesn't work when it's the first button.

If I move it to the other side of twitter it will work fine, but now twitter doesn't work.

Just looking to see if anyone has run into that issue and if they have fixed it.

here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onLoadHandler()
{
    var userAction = new gigya.services.socialize.UserAction();
    userAction.setTitle("<%=title%>");
    userAction.setDescription("<%=description%>");
    userAction.setLinkBack("<%=currentPage.toString()%>");

    gigya.services.socialize.showShareBarUI({
        containerID: "shareBarUI",
        shareButtons: "linkedin, twitter,googleplus-interactive,facebook,email",
        userAction: userAction,
        showEmailButton: true,      
        emailBody : "I thought you'd like this:<br/><br/>$URL$<br/><br/>$title$<br/><br/>$userMsg$",
        iconsOnly: false,       //iconsOnly: "false"
        showCounts: 'none',     //showCounts: "none"            
        onLoad: function(e)
        {
            var advancedShareProviders = new Array("linkedin", "twitter",  "googleplus-interactive", "facebook");
            var container = $("#" + e.containerID);

            var buttons = $(".gig-button-container", container);
            buttons.each(function(i, button)
            {
                button = $(button);

                var provider;
                $.each(advancedShareProviders, function(i, advancedShareProvider)
                {
                    if(button.hasClass("gig-button-container-" + advancedShareProvider))
                    {
                        provider = advancedShareProvider;
                    }
                });

                if(provider)
                {
                    $(".gig-button", button)
                        .attr("onclick", "")
                        .on("click", function(e)
                        {
                            gigya.socialize.showShareUI({
                                enabledProviders: provider,
                                showMoreButton: false,                              
                                showEmailButton: true,
                                userAction: userAction // Fetched from function scope

                            });
                        });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Popeye,

I am one of the engineers at Gigya and I think I can help you out. Correect me if I'm wrong but it seems like what you are trying to do is actually showShareUI() but you are using the shareBarUI() to load those buttons for you. This is causing a conflict because the two mechanisms should work independently, you are using one to trigger the other.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Knowing this I can get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Hi CodeMonkey, I'm just trying to get it to work. I'm not sure why the first button wouldn't fire off. If i go into Firebug and edit the HTML code surrounding LinkedIn and create a new space the button will than fireoff

Answer (score 0):

As I am looking through your code it is obvious that the end result is to get the sharing dialog to come up when clicking any of the share buttons. This is different from the default behavior of the share bar UI. The default is to perform the share action.

What I would recommend here is to build your own set of social buttons and attach the event listener in your "onLoad" callback to each of the buttons you created.

Right now you are using a plugin inside of another plugin trying to override the first plugins original functionality, which is getting into unstable territory and probably the cause of your issue.